# View desktop viewport within a window in macOS

Tags: macos

I use my desktop to visually organize files/folders in 2 dimensions. But typically, I want to use this arrangement side-by-side with a window from some other application. This is hard to do, because those windows necessarily obscure part of the desktop.

I find it frustrating that there is no "Desktop view" in Finder windows, so that you can have a Finder window with a "viewport" onto your Desktop (or any other directory for that matter), showing the contents arranged in two dimensions. Is there any application/extension that supports this functionality in macOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply opening your Desktop folder in Finder is about the best you're going to get.

It won't be organized like your actual desktop unless you organize it manually, but think about this: if you actually *could* have a desktop viewer, how would it be laid out? Not like your desktop, because it would only be half as wide. So it would have to reshuffle the files and folders anyway. Alternatively, you could change the spacing and icon size in your Desktop folder to 1/2 of their current settings, allowing you to display an exact replica of your desktop in one-quarter size (half-size in each dimension).

You can even set the background of the Desktop folder to your wallpaper by finding it in `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/`. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf5mZ.jpg)

Edit: To use your wallpaper as the background image in the Desktop folder, you’ll need to drag either the light mode or dark mode image  somewhere (this will create a .tiff copy) and use preview to resize it. 30% of original size works well for a quarter-size Desktop window.

Comment: Good answer, but I do think that a "desktop viewer" could retain the organization of the actual desktop-- you would just use a sliding viewport (or zoom out as you suggest).